# Email the output of a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, email

I have a shell script (script.sh) in which I run a simple python web scraper

`python3 script.py`

As I run this shell script in a cron job, I want to be notified by email if something goes wrong. I found this code on stackoverflow, which I put at the bottom of my .sh script:

```
./script.sh 2>&1 | tee output.txt | mail -s "Script log" email@address.com
```

The problem is that the script now seems to be looping; where it should only take a few seconds, it now takes a few minutes to run and I receive 10-20 emails in my mailbox. The content of these emails differs, most of the times the emails are empty, but sometimes they contain messages such as:

```
./script.sh: 4: ./script.sh: Cannot fork
```

or:

```
mail: Null message body; hope that's ok
```

I'm not sure what goes wrong here. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The script runs, runs the python, then calls itself again, until it runs out of resources and fails to fork.

The .sh should contain:

```
python3 script.py 2>&1 | tee output.txt | mail -s "Script log" email@address.com
```

Assuming you actually want to create output.txt in whatever folder pwd is... otherwise you could leave that out entirely.

Alternatively you could just configure your MAILTO in your crontab (see https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-crontab-change-mailto-settings/)

Comment: Or since tagged bash, *process substitution* is another option, e.g. `mail -s "Script log" email@address.com < <(python3 script.py 2>&1 | tee output.txt)`

Comment: I don't want the output of the python script to be emailed. My goal is to have multiple python scripts running in the shell script, and I want to send the log to my email account, to see if they all run correctly.

Comment: If you're writing a log file somewhere you can just cat that to mail at the end of the script like: cat /path/to/log | mail -s "Script log" email@address.com  or if you just need the output of your shell script, crontab can handle that for you, with the added benefit that assuming the script is silent on success it will only send an email if there's errors. Depends what you mean by 'the log'?

Comment: Sorry I'm not that technical. With log I mean the output that is provided in the terminal screen. Whenever there's an error, I want the script to email me so I can see what the error is. Not just the latest error, but all errors that have been returned (so could be from multiple python scripts).

Comment: Yeah, just set MAILTO=email@address.com in your crontab then, should do exactly what you want.

Comment: I've added the line but it doesn't work.. It doesn't send me an email.

Comment: Appologies, been away. You added the line to what?

Comment: If you added it to crontab before the script runs, it should work. If the script creates output to STDOUT you should get an email with the subject line of "whatever the line in the crontab is" and the output, if the script is silent there's no email. I'd check your local maillog to see if it's attempting to send.. it's also pretty common for examples of cron jobs to have "> /dev/null" at the end, which supresses output, you don't want that.